# Should I make a private method public just for testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core

I have a C# service with two methods:

```
private IEnumerable<RowsBalance> GetUpdatedRowsBalance(IEnumerbale<OrderRows> rows)
{
    //Do something important I want to test
}

public void UpdateBalance(int orderId)
{
    //Gets order rows from database
    var rows = orderRepository.GetRows(orderId);

    //Get updated balance
    var updatedBalanceRows = GetUpdatedRowsBalance(rows);

    //Save updated balance to database
    orderRepository.SaveBalance(updatedBalanceRows);
}
```

The private method has the logic I need to test, what should I consider in order to make my code testable ?

I'm thinking about:

- Make `GetUpdatedRowsBalance` public and test that. Is it ok to make something public that will never be called outside of testing ?
- Separate the important business logic I need to test on a different class. Still ok but this is not going to be reused elsewhere.
- Make the public method returns something I can assert like `updatedBalanceRows`. I don't really like returns something I don't need just for testing.

I'm note sure how to approach this scenario.

Comment: If it is truly the `GetUpdatedRowsBalance` you want to test, then I'd say yes. It should be public/internal. However. If it is truly a private function that should not be exposed then I'd say it should be tested through the method `UpdateBalance` that uses it. Should be easy enough by mocking the `orderRepository` and assering the input to `SaveBalance`.

Comment: I'd say, if what you want to test is really a behaviour of the class so that the private method is an implementation detail, then no, don't make it public. Tests are meant to specify the behaviour of your component by invoking them as a client would (that is, through their public methods)

Comment: If, on the other hand this is a behaviour that belongs in a separate class then it does make sense to test that separately. But I wouldn't make the method public to test it initially. I'd write a test that exercises the behaviour from the class it's in, then refactor to introduce the new class. Tests give you safety to refactor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could test it as it is.

Just create your own version of `orderRepository`.

Here's an example of a very crude API, alter to your preference (or use Moq if you are that way inclined).

```cs
// The Test

// Arrange
var orderRepositoryDouble = new OrderRepositoryDouble();
orderRepositoryDouble.Rows = someFakeRows;
var sut = new Whatever(orderRepositoryDouble);

// Act
sut.UpdateBalance();

// Assert
var updatedRows = orderRepositoryDouble.UpdatedRows;

// Whatever.

// The test double
class OrderRepositoryDouble : IRepo
{
    public IEnumerable<OrderRows> Rows { get; set; }
    public GetRows(int orderId) => Rows;

    public IEnumerable<RowsBalance> UpdatedRows { get; set; }

    public void SaveBalance(IEnumerable<RowsBalance> r) =>
        UpdatedRows = r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in the end I mocked orderRepository using moq and tested the parameters passed to the SaveBalance method. Works good.